# Sherlock actionbar and 2.3 has unresponsive options menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an application that has an options menu in fragments that works perfectly in 4.0. But when i test it in 2.3 i get a weird issues. When i click on an option menu it doesn't cause any events to trigger. But if i do anything else after like click back, click a button, open another activity. The event that was supposed to happen when i click the action button triggers.

I have setHasOptionsMenu(true); in my fragments the only thing different that maybe the source of the issue is that my fragments inherit from a base fragment that has the logic for the action buttons.

```
---Base Class --- 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    if(menu != null)menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.msg_menu, menu);
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                 //Logic Here
             }
}
```

To make this issue more strange sometimes the button in the actionbar will behave normally but i can't figure out why.

**EDIT:** I found that if i press a menu button then open and shut the navigation drawer. The button then work correctly after but still haven't found a work around